# How to draw Driver Log Chart (HOS) in android

Tags: android, charts

I want to create Drive Log chart in android.I am searching but i have not got any proper solution.I have used the StepLineChart.But I am not getting any help from it.So please provide me link or sample that help me.I want to create like
https://lh4.ggpht.com/NyTmMiNMA82lfey2HnDgKZi-KmMEKCf0cUA7M2SoDlJNRgbmfvB21_6xfvsVVLL2PQ=h900

Comment: Hey any update for chart?

Comment: Did u achieve Hos chart @Deepak?

Comment: @deepak If you have not achieve this till yet create this chart in web using javascript then render created chart in Android webview